# JavaScript for loop returns last item in array only

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the following function below with two for loops looping through a JSON file. The problem that I am having is in the second loop that is called in the barFactory function it is returning only the last item in the array. How do I resolve this has I am calling the chart object to create on each iteration so it shouldn't be happening according to my logic.

```
var looper = function(sec0, vz, lOrR) {

    $('#' + lOrR + 'Title').text(sec0);

    for (var i = 0; i < vz[0]['Areas'].length; i++) {
        var tText = Object.keys(vz[0]['Areas'][i]);
        var root = vz[0]['Areas'][i][tText][0];
        barFactory(root, sec0, lOrR, i, tText);

    }

    function barFactory(sec1, sec0, lOrR, i, tText) {
        var dataName;

        for (var j = 0; j < sec1[sec0].length; j++) {
            charts.title.text = sec1[sec0][j]["Label"];
            dataName = sec1[sec0][j]['Metrics'][5]['Rep Res. %'].slice(0, -1);
            charts.series[0].name = dataName;
            charts.series[0].data = [parseFloat(dataName)];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(charts);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're trying to create a new Highchart for each item in your `Areas` array.  What are you trying to do with the chart?  It doesn't appear that you're returning it or appending it to the DOM

Comment: I have separate section which I didn't include which appends it to the DOM. Draws the bar chart but only draws the last one in the array.

Comment: It's not "returning" anything; it's not clear how it's supposed to work without some more information. `charts` always refers to the same thing, too.

Comment: Are you changing the renderto parameter with each chart?

Comment: Yes, I am including the `renderTo` as well.

Comment: The strange thing is that if I output what I want to the console it returns what I need but it seems HighCharts is not rendering each iteration for some reason.

Comment: Why did you use a separate `barFactory` function, instead of putting the code just inside the loop body? Also, where are `charts` and `chart` defined? You probably have a scope problem.

Comment: I used a separate function to make it cleaner. Charts are defined else were. To clarify again it is drawing the charts but only for the last item in the array. I don't think that would been it is a scope problem.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird you were partially right it is `renderTo`. However, I am calling it but since there are two for loops when it goes through the second loop it over writes the first loops `renderTo` because the array are `[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]`. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:
- as Barbara said, we don't see that you are changing renderTo parameter
- you are using the same object for chart creating which may cause some errors

What I suggest to do:

```
var dataName = dataName = sec1[sec0][j]['Metrics'][5]['Rep Res. %'].slice(0, -1);
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(
    Highcharts.merge(charts, {
        chart: { 
           renderTo: new_container_variable
        },
        title: {
           text: sec1[sec0][j]["Label"]
        }, 
        series: [{
            data: [parseFloat(dataName)],
            name: dataName
        }] 
    })
 );
```

Also, aer you sure that: `dataName = sec1[sec0][j]['Metrics'][5]['Rep Res. %'].slice(0, -1);` - path after `sec1` is proper one? Try to `console.log(dataName);` to make sure that you are passing proper value, and Highcharts makes something wrong..